# Calculate the percentage of value using Collection framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, collections, java-stream

I have List of **TrainingRequest** where each and every element has List of **Feedback**.

```
@Data
class TrainingRequest{
    @Transient
    List<Feedack> feedback;
}

@Data
class Feedback{
    String Q1;
    String Q2;
}
```

I need to get all given result of Q1,Q2 and calculate percentage of each value.

```
List<TrainingRequest> trainingList = Optional.ofNullable(trainingRequestList).orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
                                    .stream().map(m -> {
                                        List<Feedback> feedback = findByTrainingRequestId(m.getId());
                                        m.setFeedback(feedback);  // assigning Feedack to TrainingRequest
                                        return m;
                                    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To flat all the feedback

```
List<Feedback> flatMap = trainingList.stream().flatMap(f -> f.getFeedback().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To calculate each value of Q1 and Q2, I'm grouping it and getting the count. I need to get the percentage of each Q1, Q2 value insted of count.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> map = new TreeMap<>();

map.put("Q1", flatMap.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Feedback::getQ1, Collectors.counting())));
map.put("Q2", flatMap.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Feedback::getQ2, Collectors.counting())));
```

When I use `Collectors.counting()`, it's giving the following output:

```
{
  "Q1": {
    "unsatisfied": 2,
    "Satisfied": 1,
    "satisfied": 1
  },
  "Q2": {
    "Yes": 4
  }
}
```

But I need it to give percentage as I expected

```
{
  "Q1": {
    "unsatisfied": 50 %,
    "Satisfied": 25 %,
    "satisfied": 25 %
  },
  "Q2": {
    "Yes": 100 %
  }
}
```

How to do it in a efficient way? Do I need to optimize the above code?

Comment: I'm a little confused with the code snippets you've posted, do you have a full example I can just dump into an IDE and run?

Comment: Im getting data from database, and this is how I implemented and working fine. I thinky ou can go with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be an optimized answer but you can get the result. 
Create a map to keep total values for each Q, and then use it to calculate percentage,

```
Map<String, Long> totalCountMap = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().values().stream().reduce(Long::sum).orElse(0l)));

Map<String, Map<String, Long>> result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e1 -> (e1.getValue() * 100 / totalCountMap.get(e.getKey()))))));
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried related to something your code, But the problem is how to optimized it. But this code is perfectly working.

Answer (score 4):

Your question was a bit unclear, so I tried to simplify the logic a bit for myself. I came up with a snipit to calculate the percentage of even/odd integers in an `IntStream` (which is not so different than what you're trying to do).

```java
IntStream.range(0, 101).boxed()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(integer -> (integer % 2) == 0 ? "even" : "odd",
             Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(), aLong -> aLong + " %")));
```

Notice the use of the `collectingAndThen()` this let's us first `collect` the values, then map the result into another value using a `mapper/finisher`.

In your case, this would be translated into something like this

```java
map.put("Q1", flatMap.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Feedback::getQ1,
Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(), count -> (count / flatMap.size()) * 100.00 + " %")));

map.put("Q2", flatMap.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Feedback::getQ2,
Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(), count -> (count / flatMap.size()) * 100.00 + " %")));
```

---

## UPDATE

Since you specifically asked about optimization, here are a couple of points to that

### 1. Don't create a new collection when you can reuse the existing one

```java
// this code is unnecessarily creating a new collection
List<TrainingRequest> trainingList = Optional.of(trainingRequestList).orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
                                    .stream().map(m -> {
                                        List<Feedback> feedback = findByTrainingRequestId(m.getId());
                                        m.setFeedback(feedback);  // assigning Feedack to TrainingRequest
                                        return m;
                                    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

it could be simplified to this

```java
// to avoid NullPointerExceptions
trainingRequestList = trainingRequestList == null ? Collections.emptyList() : trainingRequestList;
// because java is pass by reference we are able to do this
trainingRequestList.forEach(m -> m.setFeedback(findByTrainingRequestId(m.getId())));
```

### 2. Don't Collect if you are going to stream the collection again

```java
// to hold the count of Q1 an Q2
final Map<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();

//  Order(n), n = trainingRequests count
trainingRequestList.forEach(trainingRequest -> {
   List<Feedback> feedbacks = findByTrainingRequestId(trainingRequest.getId());
   //  Order(m), m = feedbacks count
   feedbacks.forEach(f -> {
     count.merge("Q1", f.getQ1(), Integer::sum);
     count.merge("Q2", f.getQ2(), Integer::sum);
   });
   trainingRequest.setFeedback(feedbacks);
}

// finally we can collect the percentage
// Order(1)
int totalCountOfFeedbacks = count.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
Map<String, String> result = count.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> 100.00 * (entry.getValue() / totalCountOfFeedbacks ) + " %"));
```

Notice that these optimizations will not affect the fact that your logic is currently `Order(n * m)`, it would be difficult to provide you further hints without actually looking at the code.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a of the good. I'd like to know is this really optimized!!